# Double acute accent (long Hungarian umlaut) in Wordpress (or in math mode)

Tags: math-mode, accents

Is it possible to display ő and ű characters in Wordpress' Latex?

As far as I know, the Latex of Wordpress works in math mode, but it seems to me that the double accute (long Hungarian umlaut) is missing from the [accents of math mode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Math_mode).

Is there any workaround for this?

**Edit**: I need these characters inside a {cases} block, so WP editor doesn't solve this.

Comment: WordPress 'LaTeX' is not really LaTeX but MathJax, which uses the same syntax as LaTeX/TeX, but applies a totally different approach in the background. I fear, your question is off-topic. I think you could get your characters with long Hungarian umlauts the usual way by unicode characters or copying over from a symbol table/special characters map in the WP editor basically the same way you achieved to display them in your question above

Comment: I don't think this off-topic, because I need these characters inside a {cases} block, and I can't combine the WP editor with my formula.

Comment: It's still **not** LaTeX what you're using there, regardless whether it's the `cases` block etc or not

Comment: You are probably right, but isn't this a hairsplitting? Wordpress calls this latex and the syntax is also $latex. But, of course, I would be glad if you had an idea for a better place for this question.

Comment: Long ("Hungarian") umlauts are to be used in text mode only -- at least in PlainTeX and LaTeX. (I can't speak to WordPress...) That's the reason why `\H{o}` (and `{\H o}`) have not been set up for use in math mode. If you absolutely have to write `Erd\H{o}s` in a math context, simply encase the entire word in a `\text` wrapper: `\text{Erd\H{o}s}`.

Comment: @mma No, it's not hair splitting: one could easily add in LaTeX a math accent for the long umlaut, but the code won't work in MathJax. What's the real application? Is it for a text that happens to appear in `cases` or is it a for a math accent?

Comment: It is a text (specifying the cases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mico's advice solved my problem.

This works in Wordpress:

```
$latex \text{Erd\H{o}s}$
```

and all Hungarian accents are available so:

```
$latex a=\begin{cases}
1, &amp; \text{\'{a}rv\'{i}zt}\text{\H{u}r\H{o} t\"{u}k\"{o}rf\'{u}r\'{o}g\'{e}p} \\
0, &amp; \text{\'{A}RV\'{I}ZT}\text{\H{U}R\H{O} T\"{U}K\"{O}RF\'{U}R\'{O}G\'{E}P}
\end{cases}$
```

Comment: i'm sure i don't really know what i'm talking about, but it's unclear why the right-hand side of the `cases` can't be a single `\text{...}` string rather than two.